# Проверка определения типа правила

Tags: javascript

(Приведенный ниже ответ неправильный, т.к. в нем проверялись другие условия) Есть два массива - termianl и neterminal. при добавлении правил должно определяться к какому типу грамматик Хомского относится добавляемое правило.
Грамматика типа 3: в inputw1 должен находиться единственный символ из neterminal, а в inputw2 цепочка из символов из termianl и символа из neterminal, который может быть либо первый,либо последний, либо отсутствовать (например, D-->azdA, A-->Ddz).
Контекстно-свободная грамматика:  В inputw1 должен стоять только один символ из neterminal, а в inputw2 может быть любая цепочка символов из terminal и neterminal, в том числе пустая (например, A-->zdA, D-->dzb).
Контекстно-зависимая грамматика: строка из  inputw1 должна содержать символ из neterminal, который огоржден  'контекстом' (например, S-->abc - контекстно-свободная, а aS-->abc - контекстно-зависимая).  Не понимаю как правильно сделать,чтобы определялся 3 тип.

```js
var terminal = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var term=document.getElementById('terminal').innerHTML = terminal;

var neterminal = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'];
var neterm = document.getElementById('neterminal').innerHTML = neterminal;
function pushTerminal(){
    var x = document.getElementById('newTerminal');
    var str = term.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    var str2 = neterm.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    if(str == -1 && str2== -1) {
          term.push(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
            x.innerHTML = term.join();
}else{
        alert("Элемент уже существует");
    }
}
//функция определния типа правила
function determineType(str, dict, caseSensitive) {
    if(!str.length){
        return false;
    } else if (typeof dict === 'string'){
      var dict = dict.split('');
    } else if (!(dict instanceof Array || !dict.length)){
        return false;
    }
    var flags = caseSensitive ? 'g' : 'gi';
    var idx = -1;
    var count, result;
    result = !dict.some(function(v, i){
        count = (str.match(new RegExp(v + '',flags))||[]).length;
        return ((count === 1) && (idx<0)) ? (idx = i, false) : (!count ? false : true);
    });
    return (result && (idx>-1))? idx : false;
}

var changeStringFromRules = [];
var changeStringToRules = [];
function pushRules(thisBtn){
    var frm = thisBtn.parentElement;
    var w1 = frm.inputw1.value;
    var w2 = frm.inputw2.value;
    var i1 = determineType(w1, neterminal, true);
    var i2 = determineType(w2, neterminal, true);
    var rt = (i2 !==false) ? 'Контекстно-зависимая грамматика' : ((i1!==false)? 'Контекстно-свободная грамматика' :  '');
    changeStringFromRules.push(w1);
    changeStringToRules.push(w2);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = w1+'-->'+w2 +' '+ rt;
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
    var removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
    removeBtn.type = "button";
    removeBtn.value = "Удалить";
    removeBtn.onclick = remove;
    li.appendChild(removeBtn);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);

}


function remove(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    el.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
    <div class="terminal">
        <h2>Терминальный алфавит: </h2>
        <div id="terminal"></div>
        <h2>Новый Терминальный алфавит: </h2>
        <div id="newTerminal"></div>
        <div class="addTerminal">
            <h3>Добавление терминала</h3>
            <form>
                <input id ="inputAdd" type="text">
                <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="pushTerminal()">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="neterminal">
        <h2>Нетерминальный алфавит: </h2>
        <div id="neterminal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="addRules">
    <h3>Добавить правило</h3>
    <form>
        <label>w1:</label><input name="inputw1" type="text"><label> --> w2:</label><input name="inputw2" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="pushRules(this)">
    </form>
    <h3>Правила:</h3>
    <div class="container_rules">
        <ui id="list"></ui>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а в чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Проверка на единственное вхождение в строку str любого элемента массива|строки dict.
// Возвращает индекс элемента, или false (если вхождений нет, либо больше одного). 
function singleOcrIdx(str, dict, caseSensitive = false) {
  if (!str.length)
    return false; 
  if (typeof dict === 'string')
    dict = dict.split(''); 
  if (!(dict instanceof Array) || !dict.length)
    return false; 
  let flags = caseSensitive ? 'g' : 'gi', 
      idx = -1,
      count, result; 
  result = !dict.some(function(v, i) {
    count = (str.match(new RegExp(v + '', flags)) || []).length; 
    return ((count === 1) && (idx < 0)) ? (idx = i, false) :
      (!count ? false : true); 
  }); 
  return (result && (idx > -1)) ? idx : false; 
}


// -----------------------------------------------
var terminal   = ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    neterminal = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'], 
    changeStringFromRules = [], 
    changeStringToRules   = []; 

document.getElementById('terminal').textContent   = terminal;
document.getElementById('neterminal').textContent = neterminal;

function pushRules(thisBtn) {
  let frm = thisBtn.parentElement, 
      w1  = frm.inputw1.value, 
      w2  = frm.inputw2.value,
      i1  = singleOcrIdx(w1, neterminal, true), 
      i2  = singleOcrIdx(w2, neterminal, true)
      rt  = (i2 !== false) ? 'type2' : ((i1 !== false) ? 'type1' : ''); 
  changeStringFromRules.push(w1);
  changeStringToRules.push(w2);
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = `${w1} --> ${w2} ${rt}`; 
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li); 
}
```

```css
body,
input {
  font: 16px monospace; 
}

input {
  width: 100px; 
}

#terminal, 
#neterminal {
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 16px 8px; margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<span id="terminal"></span>
<span id="neterminal"></span>
<form>
  <label>w1:</label><input name="inputw1" type="text"><label> --> w2:</label><input name="inputw2" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="pushRules(this)">
</form>
<hr>
<h3>Rules:</h3>
<div class="container_rules">
  <ui id="list"></ui>
</div>
```